# What is the probability distribution for guessing the order of 6 known cards ( A-6)?

Tags: probability-distributions

I have 6 cards on the table, Ace through 6. They are randomly placed face down in a row. I try to guess the correct order of the cards. It is possible to have zero correct guesses, or one correct, etc. I would like to know the correct distribution of the probabilities for the possible results of the guess.

Comment: I think the distribution does not have a standard name. For general facts about your problem, you may want to look at *derangements* (Wikipedia).

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of zero cards correct is 5!/6! = 1/6
The probability of one card correct is   6*4!/6! = 1/5
The probability of two correct cards is 6c2*3!/6! = 1/8
The probability of three correct cards is 6c3*2!/6! = 1/18
The probability of four correct cards is 6c4*1!/6! = 1/48
The probability of five correct cards is not possible as the 6th card is also correct
The probability of six correct cards is 1/6! = 1/720

These probabilities should sum to one, but they do not come close.

Comment: For the probability of $0$ correct, look up $D(6)$, and divide by $6!$.  They may use other notation, like $!6$. My memory is poor, but I sort of recall that $D(6)=265$.

Comment: For the number with $1$ correct, it could be any of the six. The rest have to be wrong so we get $6D(5)$.  Then as usual divide by $6!$ for the probability. It would be much better if your answer here were part of the problem statement.